# Haskell and Docker reasonable deployed image size?

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, haskell, docker, haskell-stack

I had tried building a PoC Happstack executable running in Google App Engine using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV APP_ROOT=/usr/share/app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh

COPY . ${APP_ROOT}/
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}/
RUN stack setup
RUN stack build

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["stack","exec","app-exe"]
```

This works and I was able to deploy, but the resulting image seems huge.

I think the image is about 450MB following the `stack` installation, about 1.8GB following `stack setup`, and about 3GB following `stack build`.

I think hundreds of MB seems reasonable, even up to a GB. Is there a different approach I should be taking, perhaps extracting the resulting executable to another image somehow to eliminate everything unnecessary at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfect for docker multi stage builds:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

You can apply as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04 as mybuild

ENV APP_ROOT=/usr/share/app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y && curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh

COPY . ${APP_ROOT}/
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}/
RUN stack setup
RUN stack build

FROM ubuntu:14.04

COPY --from=mybuild /path/to/app-exe /dest/app-exe #edit this line accordingly

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["stack","exec","app-exe"]
```

Everything before the second `FROM` is not included in the final image, except what you copy with `COPY --from`.

Comment: If you want to really go nuts, here's a blog post about making a Docker image with a Haskell executable in < 5 MB: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/05/haskell-web-server-in-5mb

Comment: Thanks this works sorry I was trying to test it but had also been trying to switch to 16.04 which caused some trouble. I had seen the `FROM+COPY` somewhere but missed the `AS` so didn't follow where `--from` came from.